# What are Django configurations?

Tags: python, django, configuration, pycharm

I'm setting up a Django project for the first time using Pycharm, and I'm trying to figure out what the configurations do.

I have looked online at the documentation, but it seems to be more focused towards people who already know what configurations do.

I'm assuming it is used to set up my localhost, however I'm unsure. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are you talking about the settings file? I've done a fair bit of Django on Pycharm, but am not quite sure what you are referring to.

Comment: Hey Matt, sorry for the late response! I was just talking about in the top right corner there's a box that says "add configuration". I think it's used to run the project on a localhost but I'm not 100% sure!

Comment: Well, you seem to have a lot of good answers, so refer to those to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In an informal way, we can define PyCharm configurations as a comfortable way to start a new process.

Suppose that you have a Python script called *main.py*. If you have to run it via command line you will type

```
python main.py
```

In the same way, PyCharm offers the possibility to run this script using configuration. It's sufficient create a new Python configuration and setup the script path (location of main.py) and the relative python interpreter.

In fact, can happen that some scripts must be run using a virtualenv or a specific enviroments. For this reason, at the creation of PyCharm configuration we need to specify also python interpreter.

Configurations are not used just to start python scripts, but it's possible to create different types. 
As you pointed out in your question, it's possible to create configurations also for Django. 
A typical usage in this case is to create a configuration to start the runserver.

But this is not all, because it's possible create configurations also for django commands, for migrations and also for Unit Test.

Pycharm configurations are useful because in this way, no need to setup every time all environment to start a process, but you need just to create configuration and save it. You can use it whenever you want.

Last but not least, using configurations allow you to debug your code easily. 
Configurations can be started also in debug mode.

[PyCharm documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/run-debug-configuration.html)

Comment: Thanks Giordano this answer is very helpful!

Comment: Glad to help you!

Answer (score 1):

When you run your code/project in PyCharm, maybe you need to specify some set of environment variables, the entrypoint is a particular script in your project, maybe there's some other script you always need to run first before you can run your project, or lots of other fiddly things that are a pain to type in every time.

The purpose of PyCharm "Run Configurations" is to let you save all these kind of things into a single method of running your project with a single click or shortcut.

Django Configurations are a type of Run Configurations with a few extra Django-specific config options thrown in. The default settings in the Run Configuration are sensible (running on localhost:8000), although you will need to make sure you [specify the location of your Django Settings File](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/settings/).

Comment: Thanks for your answer Rach, It was also very helpful! Notable mention!

Answer (score 0):

How I config Run/Debug Configurations in Pycharm Community:

- Add a Python Configuration
- Script path: "path to manage.py"
- Parameters: **runserver** "**host**":"**port**" "option like '**--noreload**', '**--nothreading**'"
- Python interpreter: "path to venv"

Now you are able to run with Shift + F10

Answer (score 0):

In order to pycharm general setting left-top File>Setting

screenshot..
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X95NN.png)

Python Setting....
Open a project or import
After open or import you view project name option in rigth-top bar like this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zk52w.png)

on click you can view configuration option. click it and view this form for all python or other environment setting.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qsl7l.png)